# Excel validate data based on if row has value

Tags: excel, vba, validation

When a user clicks a button I want to be able to show where there are emtpy fields based on if there is value (Can be letters or numbers, accepts anything) in column C4:C. The code should fill in all the way until column DD on that row. It should not fill any color if there are no values in column C(e.g., value in C6 and no value in C7 then stop; or value in c8 no value in C9 and value in C10 then don't trigger C9.) Based on column C If there are empty fields with the along that row then fill in the boxes with yellow color along the row until column DD (e.g., Value in C10 should highlight D10 and E10 and not highlight F10 and highlight G10 and H10). Once the user has entered a value in the yellow feild when they click the button again it should remove the yellow fill and return to no color. [Photo for Refernce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCYNX.png)

The only way I can think of my solution is by the use of VBA as I am using a button, I am not very good with using VBA and have only just recently picked it up so any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Code below that I have tried so far (Only activates on selected cells when clicked):

```vb
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim rng As Range 
    
    Set rng = Selection
    
    For Each cell in rng 
        If cell.Text = "" Then 
            cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow 
        Else 
            cell.Interior.Color = xlNone 
        End If 
    Next 
    
    Reset 
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not using conditional formatting? Maybe it would help if you provide a screenshot of a worksheet that shows what you want to achieve (coloring the cells manually)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```vb
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim rng As Range, ws As Worksheet, cell As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = ws.Range("C4:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        With cell.Resize(1, 106).Interior 'from C to DD
            If Len(cell.Value) = 0 Then
                .Color = vbYellow
            Else
                .ColorIndex = xlNone '.ColorIndex not .Color
            End If
        End With
    Next
    
    Reset
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much this code works, however, it doesn't highlight cells if there are no values above or below it. e.g. in cell C14 it highlights yellow and there is value in C15 it doesn't highlight which is correct, however, there is no value in C16 and it doesn't highlight that row. Also is there a way to still highlight the other rows even if there is a value in column C to check if there are inputs along that row up until column DD, e.g. value in C20 however no value in E20 so highlight E20 yellow?

Comment: I'm using the logic (1) loop through all cells from C4 to the last occupied cell in ColC (2) If the cell in ColC has a value, then highlight the row to ColDD (3) If the cell has a value then remove any highlight.  It would be useful if you could add a screenshot showing some sample data and your expected outcome: I'm not following your comment above.